# How do I create a Windows console application with administrator rights for an EXE file built in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, path, console-application, administrator

I created a simple [Win32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) console application to say "hello world.exe". When I open the EXE file, it doesn't have administrator rights but when I run it as administrator the console path gets changed to some `C:\sys` rather that the path of the "hello world.exe".

How do I give the administrator rights with normal open or change the path to "hello world.exe" when running it as administrator?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an [application manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) which requests Administrator privileges. This is the recommended approach.